# python loop a queue without while

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I'm now playing with multiprocessing and queue in Python 2.7 and try to print out 0 to 7 with variable p. When `while` is used as the commented codes shown in option 1, it works. However when the `for` and `iter()` are used as shown in option 2, 0 to 7 do print, yet the program never exits the loop and I have to exit manually. Any suggestions on how to modify the codes to have the loop exit normally after printing? With `iter()`, is there a way to set the `block=False` for the input arg `p.get`?

```
def try_queue():
    q = Queue()
    for i in range(10):
        q.put(i)

    p = Queue()
    for j in iter(q.get,8):
        p.put(j)

    # option 1, use while, works. 
    # while not p.empty():
    #   print(p.get()) 

    # option 2, use iter()
    for k in iter(p.get, None): # None is the sentinel here
        print(k)

try_queue()
```

[Result of option 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cIom.png)

[Result of option 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73JAr.png)

Comment: I've experimented with iter() elsewhere and it works. Just not sure how to combine it with the queue.get() function.

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to work wiht a snychronized queue? Maybe you just want a `deque`

Comment: tried  `for k in p: do_stuff(k)` and it reports `TypeError: 'Queue' object is not iterable`.

Comment: yeah I'm learning about the multiprocessing stuff and use it as a toy trial before replacing the `print(k)` with more complicated codes.

Comment: I don't think `for` loop without checking `p.empty()` will work. With default setting `block=True, timeout=None`, `p.get` will just wait until an item is available. It won't give you a `None` to `StopIteration`. And that's why loop never ends.

Comment: Thanks! So with `iter()`, is there a way to set the `block=False` for the input arg `p.get`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot easily achieve that because the `Queue` does not support the [iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types). Reason for this is the `Queue` is designed to be a message passing object rather than a container.

The `Queue.get` method does not ensure the `Queue` is [actually empty](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.empty). Therefore, keep this in mind when you are writing your logic: that's not the way a `Queue` is intended to be used. Think it more as a sort of "socket" between threads/processes.

Here are two ways to achieve what you want.

1) Create a `IterQueue` class which supports the iterator protocol.

```
from Queue import Queue

class IterQueue(Queue):
    """Queue supporting iterator protocol."""
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.empty():
            raise StopIteration()

        return self.get()

queue = IterQueue()
for element in queue:
    print element
```

2) Wrap the get call into a generator. This technically hides the while loop from your logic.

```
def get_next_element(queue):
    while not queue.empty():
        yield queue.get()

for element in get_next_element(queue):
    print element
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried both methods, the first method still cannot terminate automatically but the second method works well!